# ¿Cómo filtrar todos los datos/campos de una card?

Tags: javascript, html, card

Estuve revisando la función de JavaScript que utiliza este código y el filtro solo accede a los títulos de las tarjetas. Me gustaría poder filtrar todos los elementos de tiene cada tarjeta como el título, subtítulo y el texto presente en el cuerpo de la tarjeta.

La función de JavaScript sólo filtra el título de las tarjetas mediante el input de búsqueda pero no estoy bien preparado en ese lenguaje.

¿Alguien me puede decir qué líneas agregar para poder solucionar este inconveniente y pueda filtrar todos los campos de la tarjeta?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, title, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
  cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h5.card-title");
    if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      cards[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      cards[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Card Filter - Bootstrap 4</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <input type="text" id="myFilter" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="myItems">
      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">HTML</a></h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">head, body</h6>
            <p class="card-text">kmlkml</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">JavaScript</a></h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">dadad</h6>
            <p class="card-text">vvvvdvddv</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Python</a></h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">ddadad</h6>
            <p class="card-text">pokpo</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">C#</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">lkmlmkl</h6>
            <p class="card-text">vsvdvd.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Bootstrap 4</a></h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9992932</h6>
            <p class="card-text">ememe</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">ñlplp</h6>
            <p class="card-text">lal,a,la</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: te refieres a que tu buscador filtre por todos los campos de la tarjeta... ya que solo filtra por el título... o me equivoco

Comment: Sí eso quiero amigo

Comment: ok, entiendo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se que la respuesta ya esta aceptada, pero me gustaría añadir mi respuesta empleando la propiedad `textContent`, la misma representa el contenido de texto de un nodo y sus descendientes por ende todo el contenido del contenedor cuya clase es `card` se representa de la siguiente manera:

```
Python    <------ Título
ddadad    <------ Subtítulo
pokpo     <------ Texto o cuerpo
```

Lo que hace mas fácil la búsqueda, con cualquiera de estos métodos: indexOf, includes, o empleando regular expression.

PD: De igual manera puedes utilizar `innerText`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, title, i;
  input = document.getElementById('myFilter');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  cardContainer = document.getElementById('myItems');
  cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName('card');
  Object.keys(cards).forEach((i) => {
    cards[i].textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)
      ? (cards[i].style.display = '')
      : (cards[i].style.display = 'none');
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CodePen - Card Filter - Bootstrap 4</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="myFilter"
            class="form-control"
            onkeyup="myFunction()"
            placeholder="Search for names.."
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="myItems">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">HTML</a></h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">head, body</h6>
              <p class="card-text">kmlkml</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">JavaScript</a></h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">dadad</h6>
              <p class="card-text">vvvvdvddv</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Python</a></h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">ddadad</h6>
              <p class="card-text">pokpo</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">C#</h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">lkmlmkl</h6>
              <p class="card-text">vsvdvd.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Bootstrap 4</a></h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9992932</h6>
              <p class="card-text">ememe</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></h5>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">ñlplp</h6>
              <p class="card-text">lal,a,la</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

La clave es **seguir la lógica de tu buscador**.

---

Tu card, se compone en títulos, subtítulos y textos. Entonces, mira que aquí estamos capturando al elemento que tiene la clase `card-title`, que vendrían a ser los títulos:

```
title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h5.card-title");
```

Entonces, como te decía, sigamos la lógica, ya que dices que quieres buscar por los demás elementos (que en este caso, es el subtítulo y el texto de tu card), capturemos también las clases de esos elementos, así:

```
title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h5.card-title"); // capturo el titulo
subtitle = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h6.card-subtitle"); // capturo el subtitulo
p = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body p.card-text"); // capturo el texto
```

Y pues, el último paso es agregar estos contenidos agrupados en tu condicional `if`, ya que así estaba:

```
if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { ... }
```

Entonces, agregando a los demás elementos, sería lo siguiente:

```
if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1    ||
    subtitle.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
    p.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { ... }
```

Así indicamos que si lo que escribimos, coincide con los 3 elementos de tu card, que son el título, subtítulo y tu texto.

Con esto, ya lo tendrías.

---

Código completo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, h6, p, title, subtitle, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
  cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    
    title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h5.card-title");
    subtitle = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h6.card-subtitle");
    p = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body p.card-text");
    
    if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || subtitle.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || p.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      cards[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      cards[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="myFilter" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="myItems">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">HTML</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">head, body</h6>
          <p class="card-text">kmlkml</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">JavaScript</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">dadad</h6>
          <p class="card-text">vvvvdvddv</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Python</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">ddadad</h6>
          <p class="card-text">pokpo</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">C#</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">lkmlmkl</h6>
          <p class="card-text">vsvdvd.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Bootstrap 4</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">9992932</h6>
          <p class="card-text">ememe</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">ñlplp</h6>
          <p class="card-text">lal,a,la</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muy bueno compañero. gracias por tú ayuda. saludos!!

Comment: Adapté la función a mi sistema de biblioteca donde tengo 6.000 libros pero al momento de querer filtrar alguna libro utilizando esta función literalmente se rompe el código. Escribo una letra en el input y deja de responder la página ya qué no soporta un filtrado tan grande. Me recomendarías alguna solución? Realice está consulta en el foro como posible solución https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/585447/c%c3%b3mo-implementar-el-script-de-datatables-en-un-formato-card-de-bootsrap?noredirect=1#comment1035700_585447

Comment: Te aseguraste que todos tienen la misma clase?... el filtrado es una lógica corta y sencilla, solo que los datos que busca son grandes, así que es normal que tarde un poco al momento de filtrar una grande cantidad de datos, pero del que se *rompa* no creo que sea posible...